# Redux works in dev, seems to break in production

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, redux, electron

I have an Electron desktop application containing a React + Redux app. Redux works fine whilst running the app locally in development, but does not update components once the app has been built to a native desktop app.

Many articles and issues seem to think that the store is configured incorrectly, or that I am mutating state directly rather than updating it, or that my `mapStateToProps` function is not set up correctly.

I can't see how any of these can be an issue, as my app works during development, and I can see the store be updated and the component re-renders.

In production though, the following happen:

- The store state is initialized
- An action is dispatched
- The state updates ( I can see in the dev tools )
- None of my connected components re-render with updated props.

The only difference I can see between development and production is that within Electron, during dev the app is loaded via `http://localhost`, and during production it is loaded via `file:///`

My store is configured as:

```js
export const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
```

The store is provided as:

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <App />
</Provider>
```

I am connecting my component to the store as:

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => {
    return {
        hasLoaded: state.products.hasLoaded,
        products: state.products.products
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    getProducts: getProducts
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(ProductsList);
```

Then calling getProducts from within the component like:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getProducts();
}
```

I expect the state to be updated with the retrieved products, and then the component should re-render with the updated store state as props.

Instead, the store state is updated - [as I can see it in Redux DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC8cx.png) - but the connected component never re-renders, nor does `componentDidUpdate` get called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following to electron-webpack.config.json solved the issue, react-redux has to be whitelisted.

```
{
    "whiteListedModules": ["react-redux"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try just removing `composeWithDevTools`?

```
export const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

The example below uses the React application store. It also doesn't work with Redux devtools.

```
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  )
);
```

I removed this part before production build because it required a browser dev plugin; I hope React Native will be the same.

```
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
```

Comment: I removed the redux devtools extension before and just use redux's `compose`, but unfortunately this had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I spent many days with the same feeling and issue that you did. After detecting that in production the subscribe function from redux still worked, but react-redux was unable to connect properly, I tried downgrading and it worked.

Comment: I suggested it would be a bug, and that downgrading fixed a similar problem. I do not think it "does not provide an answer."

Comment: Then you should edit your answer appropriately, removing the questions.

Comment: @lacavazan, what version of react-redux  did you downgrade to?